# Accepting an empty value in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create function that removes dash/underscore and combine the words. however if i use an empty string i get an error string index out of range

I believe whats causing this error is because of the line below. However this is impt in my code since it gets the first letter of my string.

```
# first_char = text[0]

import re
import string

def to_camel_case(text):
    split_chars = []
    ans = ''
    small = ''

    # store the first letter in variable   
    first_char = text[0]

    # use split to separate the phrase given in text   
    for x in re.split('[-_]',text): 
        if text == None:
            return
        else:
            ans += x.title()            

    # combine the vars  
    if ans[0] != first_char:
        small += ans[0].lower() 
        return small + ans[1:]  
    else:
        return ans
```

---

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-f8cbc9c16e79> in <module>
----> 1 to_camel_case('')

<ipython-input-61-2bd3248e632d> in to_camel_case(text)
     13 
     14     ## maintain the  very first letter to its original form (lower or uppercase) and store it in a var
---> 15     first_char = text[0]
     16 
     17 

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: If your text is null then `text[0]` is an error because you cannot get the first element of a null variable. Just add `if not text: return text` BEFORE calling `first_char = text[0]`

Comment: The empty string doesn't _have_ any characters, not even one. So your code should consider this a special case

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do, but you can use ternary operator to avoid error like this `first_char = text[0] if text else ''`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read a null value by text[0] as the string is empty. You can always check the input if it is null or have value. If value exist carry on with the operation otherwise return with a response.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the response now. It gave me the idea. Yes the line below will not work if I key in an empty string since there wont be a value for index[0]. Thus as suggested in the comments I just simply added an if-else statement so that it will return false if there is an empty string then on ELSE i add basically the whole code

Answer (score 0):

Using text[0] needs that text has at least one character. So you must test if text is not empty before.

Answer (score 0):

so this should work, your spacing wasn't good and as well, I've re-done the spacing and fixed your bug. The error was caused because text doesn't have any value when you want to get the first index. It's better to put as much as you can inside the body of the function.

```
import re
import string

def to_camel_case(text = 'Test'):
    split_chars = []
    ans = ''
    small = ''
    first_char = text[0]
    # use split to separate the phrase given in text   
    for x in re.split('[-_]',text): 
        if text == None:
            return
        else:
            ans += x.title()            

    # combine the vars  
    if ans[0] != first_char:
        small += ans[0].lower() 
        return small + ans[1:]  
    else:
        return ans
to_camel_case('StACKoverFLOW')
```

**OUTPUT**
*Stackoverflow*

Comment: `to_camel_case('')` will produce the same exact error

Comment: that's the fault of the code, I've fixed it and make it work with a value but if you pass value that is equal to None what do you expect when you index it.

Comment: Nobody's passing `None` to the function. They're passing the empty string, and your code still attempts to access its first character with `text[0]`, which causes the same error.

Comment: oohhhh, but why would you pass an empty string in the first place? the second I can fix it with a simple try except clause but have to go rn